# How to disable auto-assume in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I've noticed that whenever I sign in in Google Chrome version 21.0 it automatically assumes and it automatically knows what I want to search. I basically use the address bar to search(my default search engine is Google) I don't go type Google.com on the address bar and then search from there. So what happens is that when I type something for example "vernier" for vernier caliper I'm automatically redirected to my facebook account which has a user account name of vern.ancheta.

It's really getting annoying, this happens for every search term that I used maybe even ones that I haven't used before in my entire search history in Google. It always assumes as if it knows what I'm really thinking. What's the solution for this? Is this a bug in Google Chrome or just one of its annoying features. Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: Good inquiry. Wjat bugs me is I love using the typing of `Yout` and it automatically allows me to press `Tab` and I can search within the Omnibar. But sometimes, after a history clearing (I do this periodically), the `Tab` button would input a URL that *doesn't* allow me to search inline, like a URL that's like this `Youtube.com/user/rhe8rghshdughsuerg`. Drives me crazy. I have a love-hate relationship with Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, there is still no way of disabling the feature. It has been a complaint of many users for quite some time, with google still offering no solution other than pressing the down arrow prior to hitting the return key, or consistently clearing your history so it has nothing to assume.

Forum discussion of rage discussing this exact problem:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/0DR-pLIVI5g

I'd love to see this changed myself. It drives me insane.

Comment: Is that so? I guess I'll just have to sign out of Chrome if I want to get a decent search result. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. I was hoping a few upvotes would bring in a user who has found a workaround. Guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

1. Open `C:\Users\<User>\appData\local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` in notepad (replace  with your username).
2. Search for "default_search_provider".
3. Right below it is "enabled: true".
4. Change the true to false.
5. Save the file.

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium devs don't want to implement it, see:

> We have posted many times about why we generally don't provide
>   options.  Options carry high hidden costs, largely in terms of code
>   complexity and testing burden.  The former leads to more bugs and
>   slows down development and implementation of future work, while the
>   latter often manifests as large numbers of bugs in non-default setting
>   combinations that aren't tested.  These are not theoretical concerns;
>   a number of us on the team are ex-Firefox developers and speak from
>   experience with its codebase.  Additionally, options don't solve
>   problems for most users because very few users ever change any options
>   in the browser or even know what options exist; and as options
>   proliferate it becomes difficult to find and understand the potential
>   choices even for people who don't mind wading through them.  See the
>   Seamonkey or VLC options pages for examples.  Finally, options reduce
>   the chance that the design team actually solves the real problems
>   underlying some design decision, because they become an easy "fix" for
>   any perceived issue.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334300#c43